# Sicstus Prolog: display current bindings during debugging

Tags: debugging, prolog, sicstus-prolog

I'm very new to Prolog and have been using Sicstus to help debug my code. Is there a way to view all the bindings while you are stepping through a query using `trace/0`? Or is there some other way to print out during the steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done automatically if you use the [SPIDER IDE](http://www.sics.se/sicstus/spider/). You can also show the bindings when running SICStus from within [the Emacs mode](http://www.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Emacs-Interface.html) and, finally, the debugger can print the bindings using [the 'v' debugger command](http://www.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Debug-Commands.html).

Not all variables are available since some variables may disappear due to compiler optimization. If this is a problem you can use consult/1 to run the code interpreted. This is slower but sometimes gives somewhat more details in the debugger.

Comment: consult/1 was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If using Sicstus with Emacs then `C-c C-g` will open a buffer that will display prolog bindings as you step through with trace